# Calling a Sub and returning a value

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'd like to think that I am decent at Visual Basic, but, while I was learning JavaScript the other day, I found something that seemed awesome and now I can't figure out how to do it in Visual Basic.

In JavaScript, it looks like this:

```
var someValue = getThatValue()
```

It's both calling and setting the value from the getThatValue() sub. What is the Visual Basic equivalent?

---

I've tried doing this:

```
   Private Sub main()
       Dim value = getValue()
       ' Do something with value
   End Sub

   Private Sub getValue()
       return 3
   End Sub
```

That doesn't seem to work. How can I get that to work?

Comment: in VB a method that returns a value is called a Function.  Methods that do not return values are called Sub.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
Private Sub Main()
    Dim value = getValue()
    'do something with value
End Sub

Private Function getValue() As Integer
    Return 3
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

`Sub`  don't return values and `function`s don't have side effects.

Sometimes you want both side effect and return value.

This is easy to be done once you know that VBA passes arguments by default by reference so you can write your code in this way:

```
Sub getValue(retValue as Long)
    ...
    retValue = 42 
End SUb 

Sub Main()
    Dim retValue As Long
    getValue retValue 
    ... 
End SUb
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a Property:

```
Private _myValue As String
Public Property MyValue As String
    Get
        Return _myValue
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        _myValue = value
     End Set
End Property
```

Then use it like so:

```
MyValue = "Hello"
Console.write(MyValue)
```

Comment: Of course, VB.NET has auto properties now, so the one line `Public Property MyValue As String` is sufficient. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293589.aspx

Comment: Sure but its best to know what its really doing as you can't use shortcuts all the time. Eg. if you want to change Set to a different modifier such as Private. The shortcut is essentially writing the above code for you.